# Integrate EntityObject and EntityModel of its

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have entity object, for example: Article that auto generated from EF. If I'll create model (for create, edit entity object) following way:

```
public class ArticleModel
{
    // properties
}
```

in Create, Edit action I'll set to each properties of entity from model. 
Usually, I use following class for auto set properties from model to entity and auto load properties from entity to model:

```
public interface IEntityModel<TEntity> where TEntity : EntityObject
{
    void LoadEntity(TEntity t);
    TEntity UpdateEntity(TEntity t);
    TEntity CreateEntity();
}

public class EntityModel<TEntity> : IEntityModel<TEntity> where TEntity : EntityObject
{
    public virtual void LoadEntity(TEntity t)
    {
        var entityType = typeof(TEntity);
        var thisType = this.GetType();
        PropertyInfo[] entityProperties = entityType.GetProperties();
        PropertyInfo[] thisProperties = thisType.GetProperties();
        PropertyInfo temp = null;

        lock (this)
        {
            thisProperties.AsParallel()
                   .ForAll((p) =>
                   {
                       if ((temp = entityProperties.SingleOrDefault(a => a.Name == p.Name)) != null)
                           p.SetValue(this, temp.GetValue(t, null), null);
                   }); 
        }
    }

    public virtual TEntity UpdateEntity(TEntity t)
    {
        var entityType = typeof(TEntity);
        var thisType = this.GetType();
        PropertyInfo[] entityProperties = entityType.GetProperties();
        PropertyInfo[] thisProperties = thisType.GetProperties();
        PropertyInfo temp = null;

        lock (t)
        {
            entityProperties.AsParallel()
                   .ForAll((p) =>
                   {
                       if (p.Name.ToLower() != "id" && (temp = thisProperties.SingleOrDefault(a => a.Name == p.Name)) != null)
                           p.SetValue(t, temp.GetValue(this, null), null);
                   }); 
        }

        return t;
    }

    public virtual TEntity CreateEntity()
    {
        TEntity t = Activator.CreateInstance<TEntity>();

        var entityType = typeof(TEntity);
        var thisType = this.GetType();
        PropertyInfo[] entityProperties = entityType.GetProperties();
        PropertyInfo[] thisProperties = thisType.GetProperties();
        PropertyInfo temp = null;

        lock (t)
        {
            entityProperties.AsParallel()
                   .ForAll((p) =>
                   {
                       if (p.Name.ToLower() != "id" && (temp = thisProperties.SingleOrDefault(a => a.Name == p.Name)) != null)
                           p.SetValue(t, temp.GetValue(this, null), null);
                   }); 
        }

        return t;
    }

}
```

in this way, If model was inherited from EntityModel and property names match with entity properties
, in create and edit action I may write:

```
        // for create entity
        Article a = model.CreateEntity();
        // for update entity
        a = model.UpdateEntity(a);
        // for load from entity
        model.LoadEntity(a);
```

I know my class weakness. For example, If some properties not edited from view, in UpdateEntity() method old values of entity will be deleted.

**Question** : Does exist another way or common way which I don't know?

Answer (score 0):

Basically you are writing the whole update-a-model-with-the-changes-from-the-posted-webpage yourself. MVC can do this out of the box. Controllers have a method called [UpdateModel](http://www.brettnagy.com/post/2009/07/21/ASPNET-MVC-Collections-Forms-with-UpdateModel.aspx), which updates the model.

Examples can be found [here](http://www.brettnagy.com/post/2009/07/21/ASPNET-MVC-Collections-Forms-with-UpdateModel.aspx), [here](http://www.joe-stevens.com/2010/02/17/asp-net-mvc-using-controller-updatemodel-when-using-a-viewmodel/) and [here](http://forums.asp.net/t/1687833.aspx/1?asp%20net%20). More information about how it works, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1230069/what-does-the-mvc-controller-updatemodeltt-actually-try-to-do).